# Slack web api reactions.add can't find channel

Tags: node.js, slack

I'm using `@slack/web-api` npm package and creating a simple deploy notifications slack bot for our team. But suddenly stuck being unable to [send an emoji reaction](https://api.slack.com/methods/reactions.add) to a message:

```
  const main_msg_ts = "16XXXXXX1.002700";

  // This works perfectly.
  const result = await web.chat.postMessage({
    text: msg,
    channel: "deploy-notifications-test",
    thread_ts: main_msg_ts
  });

  // But this raises an exceptpion "An API error occurred: channel_not_found".
  await web.reactions.add({
    name: "checkered_flag",
    channel: "deploy-notifications-test",
    timestamp: main_msg_ts
  });
```

I have the required scopes set for my bot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter `channel_id` for channel

```
    await web.reactions.add({
    name: "checkered_flag",
    channel: "<channel_id>",
    timestamp: main_msg_ts
  });
```

Comment: What is a channel_id and how is that different from what I'm using - `channel: "deploy-notifications-test"`?  Comparing the docs of https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage and https://api.slack.com/methods/reactions.add - it should be the same.

Comment: It looks like web.reactions.add doesn't take a channel name as a value for channel whereas web.chat.post can take a name or channelId.  It seems inconsistent.

Comment: Ahhhh reactions api probably does not support private groups. /o
Thank you!

Comment: Damn it, 2 years later and I stumble upon the same issue and managed to google my own SO question. Still not sure how it should work.

Comment: Slack is full of shit, I've figured it out after reading this thread https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-client/issues/270 and using that https://help.socialintents.com/article/148-how-to-find-your-slack-team-id-and-slack-channel-id to find the channel ID instead of name. Same applies for chat.update message.